# How to manually tell systemd to not wait, but abort a job, during boot?

Tags: systemd, boot, livecd

With several Distro "live-cd"s I have run into the situation where while starting systemd (the `init` used) it will reach a point where there is an output similar to:

```
A start job is running for LSB: Raise network interfaces. (1min 20s / no limit)
```

often related to some network magic setup.

I have tried any key combination I already now, it have yet been unable to tell `systemd`: "I do not care about the network yet, just go on bootup the GUI/ or to the login prompt (text mode). I will setup the network myself"

What this answer seeks is a way to skip/abort/cancel a job in the systemd target chain. I expressively seek no information about why there is the problem to start with (I am aware why the network daemons might wait for ARP/DHCP etc etc.).

I seek a generic way to kill a systemd service which needlessly blocks boot to GUI/login prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem as well and I worked around it by disabling the networking service and starting it manually after login. Cable not being plugged in would cause a significant increase in boot up time